# Comet/JS/PHP/HTML5 versus Flash in secure Multiplayer Gamedevelopment

Tags: flash, comet

I would like to create a **multiplayer** online game (tic-tac-toe/chess) and i am not sure which language to use.

I am familiar with JS/PHP and heard about [comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)

Does comet stand a chance against Flash, if yes whats the limitations except the lack of smooth animations like flash allows?

What are the differences regarding resources and memory needed?

SECURITY:
Is it possible to create Flash-games without any chance to modify (flash-)cookies etc... for cheating?

i know lot of questions, i do hope for your recommendations into the reight direction.

Thanks 4 your time

Comment: Have you looked into going the NodeJS/SocketIO route? that seems pretty multiplayer friendly for JS/HTML based games.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worth watching [Multiplayer Gaming with HTML5: Are We Ready?](http://www.vimeo.com/22549177) by [Rob Hawkes](http://rawkes.com/) of Mozilla. He covers HTML5 gaming technologies and discusses the security concerns with using JavaScript and the current solutions to these problems.

It's easier to hack JavaScript than it is Flash. But both are hackable if the user tries hard enough. The solution for the moment is don't let users do things on the client that can influence the game too much. The server still needs to ultimately be in control and validate any move. Rob discusses this in the video.

I would go with WebSockets rather than Comet as they offer lower latency and faster communication. They are also the first true standard we've got for realtime communication on the Web. Very exciting!

You can use Flash as your front-end technology with Comet or WebSockets. Pusher, who I work for, has an [ActionScript library](http://pusher.com/docs/client_libraries#actionscript) which means you can use our realtime WebSockets platform to build you game. Other technologies will also offer similar libraries in different languages.

For something as simple as tic-tac-toe I'm absolutely positive there will be no memory or resource problems to consider.

Comment: Thanks 4 sharing. i will look into WebSockets. Interesting would be a simple tic-tac-toe multiuser created in php/ajax, php/html5, php/comet, flash and WebSocket/Flash and than compare resources, lagging, etc. against each other.

Comment: That would be an interesting comparison. My main concern about the technologies would be a WebSocket or Comet server in PHP. Whilst this is most definitely possible (e.g. there's a [php websocket project](http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/) I don't think that it would scale all that well/easily. The best and most efficient server-side realtime infrastructure has been built with realtime bi-directional communication in mind. I don't have any concerns about the resource usage of the client technologies.